# Is it possible to form a one-to-one function between given finite sets? If yes, then how?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

Suppose we are given three finite sets $A, B, C$ as shown below and we have to form one-to-one function either between $A,B$ or $A,C$ by taking $A$ as domain.
$$A=\{(0,0),(0,1),(0,2),(1,0),(1,1),(1,2),(2,0),(2,1),(2,2)\} \\
B=\{(0,0),(1,1),(2,2),(3,0),(0,1),(1,2),(4,0),(3,1),(0,2)\} \\
C=\{(0,0),(3,1),(4,2),(1,0),(0,1),(3,2),(2,0),(1,1),(0,2)\}$$

So far, I am unsuccessful either to find such a function or give a counterexample to disprove. So is it possible to form such a function? If yes, then how? I am looking for an explicit formula.

Comment: Not following.  The way you've written it....just map the given element of $A$ to the element beneath it in the array.   I assume you mean something else...but what?

Comment: I assume OP is trying to find an explicit formula, which is not necessary in this case.

Comment: I am looking for an explicit formula

Comment: You don't always have explicit formulas. You could probably try and come up with some extrapolation in this case. But why? It would take far more time and far more effort than to simply write down the function as a set of ordered pairs (of ordered pairs).

Comment: @user110219 If $C= \{ 0,1,2\}$ and $D = \{4,8,1\}$, is $$f: C \to D, f(x) = \left\{ \begin{matrix} 8 & x = 0 \\ 4 & x = 2 \\ 1 &x =1 \end{matrix} \right.$$ explicitly enough? Seeing how this is also used to explicitly define piece-wise functions.

Comment: And if it isn't, please state your definition of an explicit formula.

Comment: You could pair off most of the pairs with the identity map, then you could just do trivial cases like say $f:(x,y)\rightarrow(2y,2x)$ if $(x,y)=(1,2)$ when looking for a map between A and C for example. That would be "explicit", but not very useful.

Comment: Well to say formally what the mapping could be, order first space by assigning to each element an index. Do the same to the second set, and then map $C \to {indices} \to D$. Think of it as a composition of 2 bijections.